# Adding route as child of route from another module

Tags: routes, zend-framework2

In ZF2, how can I add a route as a child of a route from another module? I'm assuming there's a way to hook into a event somewhere?

E.g. Module A defines a route for `/foo`. In Module B, I would like to add a route `/foo/bar`, by creating a `/bar` route as a child of the 'foo' one.

Comment: In addition to the answer provided by @Crisp [my Blog-Article about "Understanding ZF2 Configuration"](http://samminds.com/2013/04/understanding-zf2-configuration/) might be of interest to you. In essence, all modules configuration will be merged into one big config. With this knowledge, the answer by Crisp may be easier understandable, as ultimately you're just working with ONE Array) ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was going to try to explain, but maybe an example will be better

ModuleA

supplies a `/parent` route which has a child route of `/parent/foo`

```
// routes
'router' => array(
    'routes' => array(
        'parent' => array(
            'type' => 'Literal',
            'may_terminate' => true,
            'options' => array(
                'route'    => '/parent',
                'defaults' => array(
                    '__NAMESPACE__' => __NAMESPACE__ . '\Controller',
                    'controller'    => 'Index',
                    'action'        => 'index',
                ),
            ),
            'child_routes' => array(
                'foo' => array(
                     'type' => 'Literal',
                     'options' => array(
                          'route' => '/foo'
                          'defaults' => array(
                              '__NAMESPACE__' => 'ModuleA\Controller',
                              'controller'    => 'Foo',
                              'action'        => 'index',
                          ),
                      ),
                 ),
             ),
         ),
     ),
 ),
```

Module B

adds a child route of `/parent/bar`

```
// routes
'router' => array(
    'routes' => array(
        'parent' => array(
            'child_routes' => array(
                'bar' => array(
                     'type' => 'Literal',
                     'options' => array(
                          'route' => '/bar'
                          'defaults' => array(
                              '__NAMESPACE__' => 'ModuleB\Controller',
                              'controller'    => 'Bar',
                              'action'        => 'index',
                          ),
                      ),
                 ),
             ),
         ),
     ),
 ),
```

The route definition in ModuleB will be merged with ModuleA's when your application loads module configurations, and you'll end up with /foo and /bar as children of /parent, with both pointing to their respective module controllers.